# Reading Oracle Blob field into a text field in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to read data in an Oracle table to populate text boxes in Python. One of the columns is a blob column that I want to use to display employee’s picture. I just don’t know how to populate a text box with image. The following code populates the employee id and first name , but not the picture.

Here is the code:

```
import cx_Oracle
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

con = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@localhost/orcl')

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, photo FROM HR.EMP WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 3000")

row = cur.fetchone()
print(cur.rowcount)
if cur.rowcount > 0:
    print('Row retrieved successfully.')

else:
    print('Data Retrieval failed.')

photo = image_types()
EMPLOYEE_ID = NUMERIC
FIRST_NAME = StringVar
cursor = con.cursor()

employee_id_entry = Entry(textvariable=EMPLOYEE_ID, width="30", background='BLUE')
first_name_entry = Entry(textvariable=FIRST_NAME, width="30", background='YELLOW')
photo_entry = Entry(textvariable=photo, width="30", background='GREEN')

employee_id_entry.place(x=10, y=10)
first_name_entry.place(x=10, y=30)
photo_entry.place(x=10, y=50)
employee_id_entry.insert(0, row[0])
first_name_entry.insert(0, row[1])
# photo_entry.insert(END, row[2])


cursor.close()
con.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is easier to use a `Label` instead of `Text` to show the image.  However, how do you store the image into the blob column?

Comment: See the cx_Oracle example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py  Unless you use a typehandler as shown, then you will need to use a Lob method to get the data, see the documentation: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#streaming-lobs-read  Note that the latest cx_Oracle release has an attribute that can be used instead of a typehandler.  This new release got renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems that before I do any coding changes, I must first verify that images are stored in the Oracle properly. currently, when I try to view photos in SQL Developer by clicking on the pencil icon, I get 'Image could not be decoded from the binary stream' message.

Comment: I used something like the following to write the image to the blob column called 'photo'. 

UPDATE HR.Emp
SET PHOTO = utl_raw.cast_to_raw('C:\Users\User Name\image_name.jpg')
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 3001;

Comment: You could try doing an INSERT with Python.  I'll add some code in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code showing how to fetch in cx_Oracle using the latest Oracle driver (which got renamed from cx_Oracle):

```
# drop table t;
# create table t (b blob);

import oracledb
import os

oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False  # fetch LOBs as string / bytes

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
pw = os.environ.get('PYTHON_PASSWORD')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Insert an image from a file

with open("oraclelogo.jpg", "rb") as f:
    imagein = f.read()

cursor.execute("insert into t (b) values (:bv)", [imagein])

# Read the BLOB column and write to a new file

cursor.execute("select b from t")
imageout, = cursor.fetchone()

with open("out.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(imageout)
```

If you are still using the cx_Oracle namespace, then you'll need to add a typehandler as shown in [return_lobs_as_strings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py) because `oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs` is only in the latest release.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the information. With what you have shown above, I was able to insert an image and verify in SQL Developer that it worked. Just had to add a commit to the code. I am still not sure how to display the image in a field. In the original example I have listed above, employee_id and first_name are populated correctly. Photo column is not. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I'm not a tkinter user.